# How do I move through intellisense suggestions with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I write something like `Console.` I get suggestions like `Console.Write` and `Console.WriteLine`. I don't want to use the arrow keys, they are too far away, how do create a shortcut for that? I would prefer something like `shift+o` for moving up and `shift+k` for moving down.

Comment: What do you mean, the arrow keys are too far away?  How is using Shift+o easier then using the arrow keys?!

Comment: When I type `Console.` , my hands are on the left side of the keyboard, now if I want to reach the arrow keys, I have to move my right hand up and towards the right side where the arrow keys are.

Comment: @Blub - How will that work, as when you press `SHIFT+o` or `SHIFT+k` you will select suggestions beginning with 'O' or 'K'? Do you type `Console.` with only one hand? What type of keyboard are you using?

Comment: Piers, I think you just need to try it and then you see what I mean.

Comment: `C`, `o`, `n`, `s`, `o`, `l`, `e`, `.` (last character typed with my right hand which can move a little more to the right to press the arrow keys on my standard UK QWERTY keyboard very easily) I can't say that `shift+o` and `shift+k` would work for me.

Comment: Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153541/scrolling-through-visual-studio-intellisense-list-without-mouse-or-keyboard-arro

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrolling through Visual Studio Intellisense list without mouse or keyboard arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153541/scrolling-through-visual-studio-intellisense-list-without-mouse-or-keyboard-arro)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try TouchCursor, it lets you use the home keys as cursor key

[TouchCursor](http://touchcursor.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

You can always remap the keyboard shortcuts to do what you want. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18744507/958809

Answer (score 1):

I don't if there is an alternative for navigating one by one but you can use the first letters of every word to quickly find what you are looking for.

Typing `Console.wl` will quickly bring up `Console.WriteLine`. It's available by ReSharper I think.

You don't even have to type the first letters by the order. Typing `avl` can bring up `SomeMethodWithAVeryLongName`.

Comment: If I type `Console.wl` it comes u with 2 choices - `WriteLine` and `WindowLeft`, I would have to type `Console.WLi` to get the one I wanted, although once you select one it does default to it next time.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know solutions within Visual Studio and ReSharper.
But maybe a remapping of keyboard keys can help, i.e. remap *Caps Look* key to *Arrow Down* key. See http://www.askdrtech.com/solutions/post/How-to-change-keyboard-mapping.aspx for explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is just this: Ctrl + Alt + Space

Answer (score 0):

1. In VS Code, go to File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Search for *suggest select* in the search bar
3. the ones you want to change are `selectNextSuggestion` and `selectPrevSuggestion`. I mapped mine to TAB and shift + TAB, respectively, to free my arrow keys.

There's plenty of cool stuff you can customize for Intelisense. Check the documentation page: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense