# Scrolling through Netbeans code assistance list without mouse or keyboard arrows

Tags: java, vim, netbeans, jvi

This is basically the same question [as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153541/scrolling-through-visual-studio-intellisense-list-without-mouse-or-keyboard-arro) except for Netbeans 8.0.2 (running under jMonkeyEngine SDK 3.1-alpha1) instead of Visual Studio.

Honestly, the aforemetnioned link says it better than I can, but basically I'm a vim key binding user, and have the [netbeans jVi plugin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38914/jvi-vi-vim-for-nb-update-center) installed and want to map, for example, *alt-j* and *alt-k* to scroll through the code completion list instead of the arrow keys:

[image: How do I scroll through this list without arrow keys?]

I've searched through Tools->Options->Keymap, as well as the the JVi configs at Tools->Options->jViConfig.  I don't see anything at all under jViConfig, so I think the standard NetBeans key bindings are the way to go.

I have tried modifying most of the obvious *down* keys e.g *insertion point down*, *scroll down*, *page down* etc, but they all affect the underlying text in the editor, never the completion list.

[image]

And:
[image]

Does anyone know of a way to do this?
Or maybe a plugin to provide the functionality?
It simply appears that the raw arrow key movements are not mappable by netbeans (?).

Note: this *is* possible to do in Visual Studio 2015, so I'm hoping it's possible in NetBeans as well.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to do this in NetBeans. At least there wasn't in 2010, when I filed the NetBeans bug [hint completion makes assumptions about associated editor pane bindings](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=183675). I maintain jVi. I filed the bug since I was having trouble with completion bindings for some special keys. In the NB source take a look at

> editor.completion/src/org/netbeans/modules/editor/completion/CompletionScrollPane.java

And you'll see a bunch of hardcoded stuff.

In the jVi source

> nbvi/nbvi-module/src/org/netbeans/modules/jvi/KeyBindings.java

method fixupKeypadKeys, you see what jVi does (given the fix for the bug I filed). This is part of some arcane code that depends on being friend with some NB editor package.

You could file a bug with NB. If you provided NB a patch, they might incorporate it. If you file a NB bug, cc me (err at netbeans.org)

Alternately, you could try adding some code to the jVi file to add your keybindings.